# Why my sprite in pygame every time it changes teleports for a millisecond to the top left edge?

Tags: python, pygame

This is not a problem in itself, because it does not affect anything in the gameplay, but it is a visual bug that bothers a lot, every time it changes state between crouching and standing, the Sprite teleports to the corner for 1 millisecond, is there any way How to avoid this? Here's a piece of code that makes the sprite switch between crouching and standing.

```py
if pressKeys[K_DOWN]:
   self.surf = self.crouch_sprites[0]
   self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.surf, (30, 15))
   self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
   self.isCrouch = True
else:
   self.surf = self.run_sprites[0]
   self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.surf, (30, 30))
   self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
   self.isCrouch = False
```

[image: GIF showing the bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at **(0, 0)** since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. You have set the position of the rectangle.

e.g.: Sets the position of the rectangle with its previous position:

<s>`self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()`</s>

```py
self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(bottomleft = self.rect.bottomleft)
```

Fix in your code:

```py
if pressKeys[K_DOWN]:
   self.surf = self.crouch_sprites[0]
   self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.surf, (30, 15))
   self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(bottomleft = self.rect.bottomleft)
   self.isCrouch = True
else:
   self.surf = self.run_sprites[0]
   self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.surf, (30, 30))
   self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(bottomleft = self.rect.bottomleft)
   self.isCrouch = False
```